# How to convert PDF to Excel on a Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, pdf, ms-word

I have a lot of PDFs to convert to excel. I found the code below which converts PDF to excel by opening the pdf file in word but it fails at *Dim fso As New FileSystemObject* because mac excel does not have scripting dictionary. How do I amend the code to open the PDF files in word without having to use scripting dictionary?

```
Option Explicit
Sub pdf_to_excel()

Dim setting_sh As Worksheet
Set setting_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setting")
Dim pdf_path As String
Dim excel_path As String

pdf_path = setting_sh.Range("E11").Value
excel_path = setting_sh.Range("E12").Value

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim f As File

Set fo = fso.Getfolder(pdf_path)

Dim wa As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim wr As Object

Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")
wa.Visible = True

Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim nsh As Worksheet

For Each f In fo.Files

Set doc = wa.documents.Open(f.Path, False, Format:="PDF files")
Set wr = doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
wr.WholeStory

Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)

wr.Copy
nsh.Paste
nwb.SaveAs (excel_path & "\" & Replace(f.Name, ".pdf", ".xlsx"))

doc.Close False
nwb.Close False
Next

wa.Quit

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: There are non-programming options to do this if you are interested.

Comment: @jmh I am interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to do this which requires no programing. One is to use the app [PDFelement](https://pdf.wondershare.com/promotion/pdfelement-pdf-software-sale.html?src=cj&cjevent=845f605ca4e211ea809900940a24060d). This app is not cheap but if you scroll down on the linked site the is a free download option.  There are other ways given by [this link.](https://www.anysoftwaretools.com/convert-pdf-to-excel-mac/) One of these is an [online site](http://%20https://www.pdftoexcelonline.com/) that will convert your PDF to excel but the site has pretty generous restictions on the size of the PDF file.